# How to handle micro services communication

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, message-queue

I'm building a micro service based system that receives and process messages.

A service receives the messages, while the other processes them.

The messages received can be of 12 types and from around 20 different "users". The data then needs to be processed grouped by type and user, and each group should contain at most 100 messages.

Currently I've implemented a queue system using a MariaDB database, from which the processing service pulls the data using this queries (simplified for clarity):

```
SELECT type, user INTO t, u FROM messages GROUP BY type, user ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
SELECT message_id FROM messages WHERE type = t AND user = u LIMIT 100;
```

While discussing with some colleagues, the idea of using a queue system like RabbitMQ came up. However after looking into it, I don't think it would allow me to consume messages grouping them, unless I created [users*types] different queues.

So I was asking myself, could there be a better approach than using a DB to handle the data between the two services?

Comment: I have one question, will you get messages in bulk in your first service or you are getting single message at a time. If single message then why do you need to create grp and process? Case 1: If you get message in bulk with single request, you can grp them at your end and publish them directly Case 2: If your are getting single msg and want to process in bulk so process can be fast then you can add wait time in consumer like 1 second or as per your need. So consumer will collect all the msgs for 1 second and then start processing. Let me know if there is other use-case of grp.

Comment: I receive them in bulk but not necessarily grouped correctly. I have to send them out in bulk because it's required by the specifications that I have to follow. Moreover, the data won't be processed immediately after it's received but after a variable amount of time, that depends on the type and content of each message.

Comment: So, If you are receiving in bulk and not grouped properly then you can do the following. 1. Transfer data into the grp and publish in a queue. Here use x-delay-exchange to manage variable amount of time. 2. If you want to time variable based on grp then publish each grp individually. 3. If processing time on sync call is higher then you can introduce one publisher and consumer to receive and just forward it. And then consumer will do the process mentioned in above steps and do it job. Let me know if it will work for you. If not then please specify the response for the same.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you suggest grouping them as soon as I receive them, and pushing them in the queue already grouped. Right?

This could work, but I'm not sure if it'd be ideal. The receiver would have to do a lot to make sure everything is published correctly and in the right group, and the code maybe would become much more complex than the aforementioned queries.

Comment: I agree, But it’s still better than DB operation if time and resources are concerns. Also if you are not deleting previous records from the DB then it may start taking more time in future. And handling failure scenarios might be difficult. If it’s working fine then I am not seeing any other issues with that.